# Dagger - Dependency Injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Is this solution correct or should I create separate FragmentBuildersModules for each Activties?

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeLoginActivity(): LoginActivity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it would be better if u create a separate module for your activity and fragments, and then include it in common module `Screen module` (it should consist all your screens modules)

```
@Module(includes = [
AndroidInjectionModule::class,
RegistrationModule::class,
SecondaryModule::class,
BaseFontActivityModule::class,
SurveyModule::class,
SplashModule::class])

interface ScreenModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

The activity module:

```
    @Module
interface BaseFontFragmentModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [])
    fun inject(): BaseFontFragment

}

@Module
interface BaseFontActivityModule{

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        BaseFontFragmentModule::class
    ])
    fun inject(): BaseFontActivity

}
```

And screen module included in AppModule:

```
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: App)
}

@Module(
        includes = [
            RetroiftModule::class,
            RegistrationModule::class,
            ScreenModule::class
        ]
)
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun context(app: Application) = app.applicationContext!!

    @Provides
    fun sharedPreferences(app: Application) = app.getPreferences()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the activities reuse the same fragments, they should depend on different fragment modules. There are a couple of different reasons for this:

1) You adhere to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of SOLID;

2) Your code remains easy to read and to reuse (eg.: if you only need to reuse one of the activities on another project, you can easily port it along with its dependencies graph);

3) Your code is easier to maintain (eg.: if someone has to use your code in the future, they'll immediately know which fragments belong to which activities);

4) Your code stays less error prone (eg.: if you somehow mess your fragments module, it'll only affect one activity);

5) Probably other reasons that I can't remember right now :)